# Growth of the number of generators in hyperbolic groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite hyperbolic group, and let us further assume that it is residually finite (or even LERF/GFERF) so that we have plenty of subgroups of finite index.

I would like to know if one can impose some reasonable conditions on $G$ under which the number of generators of finite index subgroups will have to grow (asymptotically) with the index. This happens, for example, if $G$ is free nonabelian (but this is too restrictive).

***Conditions under which there is a bound from below on the subgroup growth are of course also of interest***

Comment: The existence of hyperbolic HNN extensions (eg some free-by-cyclic groups) makes this tricky.  Does it help to assume that the hyperbolic group has trivial abelianization?

Comment: The obvious comment is that the free group argument generalises to any 2-dimensional group with negative Euler characteristic. On the other hand, as Sam points out, with zero Euler characteristic this is usually false.

Comment: On the other hand, some of the arguments of this paper may be applicable: http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4192.

Comment: More generally, if the 1st $l_2$-betti number is non-zero. A related concept is cost/rank gradient. http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0701.5361

Comment: I suspect that locally quasi-convex residually finite hyperbolic groups have the property that the rank grows with the index. However, I also think that the only known examples of this type might have non-zero 1st $l_2$-betti number.

Comment: @IanAgol do you have an idea how to show that the number of generators grows asymptotically linearly with the index in the case that the first $l_2$ betti number is not zero?

Comment: It's a fact that the rank gradient of an infinite group is bounded below by the first $l_2$ Betti number.  See, for instance, http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1322 .

Comment: @HJRW thanks for that. Indeed, I am interested in the positivity of the rank gradient (or even a sublinear asymptotic lower bound) for finitely generated groups in general and not only for hyperbolic groups.

Comment: @HJRW regarding your first comment, if my group is a $2$-dimensional group with negative Euler characteristic, then I will have some formula for the rank of finite index subgroups, like Schreier's index formula in the free group, or at least the limit (and not only liminf) of $(d(H) - 1)/[F : H]$ will exist as $[F : H]$ tends to infinity, right?

Comment: @Pablo, all I meant was that, for a fi subgroup H of a 2-dimensional group G, $b_1(H) \geq 1-|G:H|\chi(G)$, by the multiplicativity of Euler characteristic. Thanks for your e-mail - I'll reply soon!

Comment: @IanAgol here's an updated link to the paper _Rank gradient, cost of groups and the rank versus Heegaard genus problem_ by Abert and Nikolov: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701361 (published as https://doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/344) (please upvote this so it appears above the fold)